# qmake hangs in windows 7

Tags: windows, qt, compilation, mingw

I have a strange error with qmake: To compile octomap, first I need to compile octovis code, accordingly with documentation I need to use:

```
    cd octovis/src/extern/QGLViewer
    qmake
    mingw32-make
```

But when I use qmake, they just do nothing, seeing the task monitor the amount of memory used is constant and the amount of processor used is 0.
I tried to uninstall/reinstall QT and MinGW, and didn't work, I have change the version of QT (4.8.5, 4.8.6, 5.5) and MinGW and didn't work, I'm using windows 7 over 64 bits. I appreciate any solution.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? I've got a very similar issue attempting to build a project in Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Yes, finaly I used the solution proposed by Christopher

Comment: Thanks, I too was able to resolve my issue. It had to do with a `$$system()` call that was waiting for input. Once that was removed, everything was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to generate the qmake files with no problem. make failed, but my environment is QT 5.5.1, which I doubt is compatible. I can tell you how my environment is set up, and that should get you going.

1. Go ahead and download QT Creator for whatever version of QT you require. This includes the appropriate mingw version, so they don't need to be downloaded separately. http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/
2. Find out what version of QT is recommended. It looks like 4.X, but I'm not 100 percent certain.
3. Add `X:/QTCREATOR/QTVERSION/mingw/bin` to your system path, with `QTCREATOR` being the root directory for QT Creator and `QTVERSION` being the version. These are included with the QT Creator install.
4. Also add `X:/QTCREATOR/Tools/mingw/bin` to your system path.

I'm assuming you have CMake already. That's obviously required.

This should have your build environment set up properly. You're sure to encounter other problems along the way.

The best option appears to just run it under Linux. There are pre-compiled binaries.

Comment: Yes, with QT 5.5.1 the command qmake works fine, but as you guess it is with 4.X , I'm trying with 4.8.6 and the command qmake never finish and do nothing.